# "Hidden" terminals on DC motor

Tags: batteries, dc-motor, multimeter

I have this DC motor that I tried testing with common sense, but doesn't work.

The description classified it as "Female terminals"

I don't have a multimeter on me now so I can't be sure about if there's "contact" being made, though I am sure that the battery works, and there are no dead shorts or broken wires.

With a multimeter what tests do I attempt? Any other information too?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two brass tabs are the contacts, inside the motor they act as springs pushing against the commutator.  As a guess I’d say that the motor could be anything from 1.5 to 12V.  If you see a low resistance (a few ohms) between the contacts then you should be ok.  If you’re testing with a 1.5V cell, try turning the shaft by hand to see whether there’s any torque -some small motors have a ‘dead’ position where the brushes don’t contact the commutator at all so they can ‘park’ without the need for an external switch.

Comment: Question about the last bit... does it mean that I simply can't jab a copper wire inside the contacts and expect it to work? This is a 12v motor that is apparently used in ''car locks''. I attempted testing it with 4x AA batteries which is 6v, I know its half the "nominal voltage" of the motor but it should at least twitch, right?!

Comment: Very likely it should at least twitch. If you turn the shaft by hand while applying voltage and get no reaction, there is very likely something broken. If you can not detect continuity between the terminals while turning the shaft, there is something broken.